# Is "throughout" used in this sentence as a verb?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> There's a lengthy bug thread on OS X Yosemite that has been added **to throughout** the beta testing period.

Source: http://www.macrumors.com/2014/07/24/os-x-yosemite-first-impressions/

Comment: Welcome to ELL! No, it's not a verb. But if you could tell us (please add it to your question with the 'edit' function) what leads you to think it **might** be a verb, it would help us clear up your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not a verb.  The sentence has been structured to place the emphasis on "bug thread" (by having it at the front), but "bug thread" is the object of "to", and "throughout" has its usual duration-based meaning; *to throughout* is not an attempted *to*-infinitive, but a simple collocation of words in unrelated functions.

We could rewrite and simplify the sentence a bit to make it more apparent:

> Items have been added to the bug thread throughout the beta testing period.

Comment: +1 Ah! I couldn't figure out what made OP think it was a verb. Nice spot.

Comment: The passive voice was the problem for me in this sentence. :) Now everything is crystal clear.